# Memberwise operator in python

Tags: python, matlab, list, vector, octave

How can I perform in Python memberwise operation on `list` (vector) such as in Matlab/Octave. I mean, giving two lists:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]
```

Are there memberwise operators such as:

```
c = a .* b = [1*4,2*5,3*6]
d = a ./ b = [1/4,2/5,3/6]
```

I know that I can implement it by myself, and I will do so if there is not such module. A not completely bulletproof way could be:

```
# Memberwise product:
def mwprod(a,b):
    c = []
    if len(a) == len(b):
        for a,b in zip(a,b):
            try:
                c.append(a*b)
            except:
                c.append(NaN)
    return c
```

As stated by `user3426575` this can be condensed in a very pythonic way:

```
c = [ x*y for x, y in zip(a,b)  ]
```

Anyway I am wondering for something more dense and aesthetic which overloads or implements such operators on `list`.

Comment: You're looking for [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/).

Comment: A very “pythonic” way to do this would be to use a list comprehension:

`c = [x * y for x, y in zip(a, b)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with **numpy**:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([1,2,3],float)  # float argument is used so that / operator does float division rather than integer division
>>> b = np.array([4,5,6],float)
>>> a*b
array([  4.,  10.,  18.])
>>> a/b
array([ 0.25,  0.4 ,  0.5 ])
```

Comment: Thanks for this module-based answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can try like this,

```
>>> [ item * b[k] for k,item in enumerate(a)]
[4, 10, 18]
>>> [ item / b[k] for k,item in enumerate(a)]
[0.25, 0.4, 0.5]
```

Comment: Thanks for this python-only based answer.

Comment: This is really a weird and incorrect way to do this. This is unnecessarily `O(N**2)` and fails if list contains duplicate items.